# Magento 2 Admin and front-end showing the error "utils"

Tags: magento, magento2

Magento 2.1.8

In Magento 2  Admin any of the grid view lists is loading it shows the Loading icon.
when I analyze it shows the error "Uncaught TypeError: utils.stringToArray is not a function".

In frontEnd, It shows the error "TypeError: utils.isEmpty is not a function".

[image]

FrontEnd

[image]

Comment: Do you have a fresh system or are there third party extensions?

Comment: It's a fresh system. I am not sure why we have this type of issue in both FrontEnd and BackEnd. Can you help me out?

Comment: It looks like require.js is not working correctly. First thing I would do is check if exception printing is enabled (rename pub/errors/local.xml.sample to local.xml) and set the system to developer mode. Also, disable all cache. If nothing comes up, check the logfiles (exception.log, debug.log, system.log and also your apache/nginx logfiles). If still nothing comes up, go to developer settings in stores->configuration->advanced and disable all js bundling and minification.

Comment: Thanks, @Tobi let me check to it and let you know the status